# Unable to populate and structure document with aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I have this schema which have foreign keys to other collections in the database. The document has around 60k posts and each post can have multiple categories and there are around 200 categories. So I'm trying to fetch and structure data based on the category's foreign key and populate the category details and count.

Here's how the main schema and category schema looks like:

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
    post: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'PostDetails'
    },
    categories: [ {
        category: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Category'
        },
        subCategories: [ {
            subCategory: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Subcategory'
            }
        } ]
    } ]
} );

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
    category: {
        type: String,
    },
    categorySlug: {
        type: String,
    }
} );
```

I was successful in making the count but the returned data is not what I expected. The returned data shows the id of the categories and the count but no name and slug. Here's how it looks like:

```
[
   {
       "_id": [
                 "617acfd232c766589c23a90c"
       ],
       "count": 876,
       "category": []
   }
]
```

I got the above output with the following query:

```
const aggregateStages = [ 
     {
          $group: {
                _id: '$categories.category',
                count: { $sum: 1 }
          }
     },
     {
          $lookup: {
                from: "Category",
                localField: "categories.category",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "category"
          }
     }
];

const categories = await Post.aggregate( aggregateStages ).exec();
```

I'm hoping to get the data as follows:

```
[
   {
       "_id": "617acfd232c766589c23a90c",
       "count": 876,
       "category": 'SomeCategory',
       "categorySlug": 'some-category' 
   }
]
```

Where am I going wrong and how can I fix it?

*******************SAMPLE DATA FROM DB AS REQUESTED BY MATT OESTREICH*******************

```
POST DATA

{
    "_id": "617adad39054bae2c983c34f",
    "post": "617ad1c80597c78ed4cc151e",
    "author": "617acc689b309fdbbbdfdfe0",
    "categories": [{
        "category": "617acfd232c766589c23a8d1",
        "subCategories":[]
    }]
}

CATEGORY DATA

{
    "_id": "617acfd232c766589c23a8d1",
    "category": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "categorySlug": "lorem-ipsum"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data from your collections? It's hard to help without even knowing what fields your data has, etc... The reason why the count is working is because you are counting before lookup and the lookup doesn't find anything so the issue is within your lookup.

Comment: Hi Matt. I have updated the post with the sample data. Please take a look.

Comment: Seems like $lookup isn't working. I commented out group stage and tried with only $lookup but it isn't populating.

Comment: Hey man, any solution? @MattOestreich

Comment: Taking a look now - sorry, I hadn't had a chance until now.

Comment: Not a problem mate. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: no worries! happy to help out. I just posted an answer FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so, it looks like you can resolve this by using the `$size` operator. The `$size` operator will give you the length (or count) of elements in an array.

[Live demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Eo3fPQhjQQ7)

### Database

```
db={
  "post": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("617adad39054bae2c983c34f"),
      "post": ObjectId("617ad1c80597c78ed4cc151e"),
      "author": ObjectId("617acc689b309fdbbbdfdfe0"),
      "categories": [
        {
          "category": ObjectId("617acfd232c766589c23a8d1"),
          "subCategories": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "categories": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("617acfd232c766589c23a8d1"),
      "category": "Lorem Ipsum",
      "categorySlug": "lorem-ipsum"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Query

```
db.post.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "categories",
      "localField": "categories.category",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "found_categories"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: "$_id",
      count: {
        "$size": "$found_categories"
      },
      "category": {
        "$first": "$found_categories.category"
      },
      "categorySlug": {
        "$first": "$found_categories.categorySlug"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

### Result

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("617adad39054bae2c983c34f"),
    "category": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "categorySlug": "lorem-ipsum",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

Although, I do not believe this will give you what you are looking for if more than one category is found. Please let me know if it doesn't work and I will try to help fix it.

Comment: Okay its not working. I have around 70k posts. All 70k  are being printed but with this ```{"_id":"617adad39054bae2c983c34f","count":0}```. I mean the ids are for categories

Comment: The lookup has issues i guess. Cause it isnt populating

Comment: Did you modify the query to match your collection names? The lookup works, as you can see int he demo. I think there is some minor issue somewhere that we are overlooking.

Comment: yeah I did. Tried so many different combinations lol. The lookup stage doesnt working on my side. I dont get a populated category.

Comment: there's something I'm missing that is making the query incorrect. Are you able to share the code? I would honestly need to look at it to best assist you. Otherwise, it's hard for me to locate the error.

Comment: Yes sure absolutely. Which part of the code do you need to check? I mean schema, or query?

Comment: Please note that I'm using Mongoose to make the query.

Comment: Yea I just realized that, I apologize.  Let me take some time to set up a demo environment in a test database I have. I will attempt to solve this by using Mongoose, but it may take me about an hour or so.

Comment: No problem mate. I just can't thank you enough for your help.

Comment: You bet. I wouldn't know half of what I do without people helping me, so I like to "pay it forward" when I can. Cheers.

Comment: That means a lot to me, thank you very much. You've just made my day!

Comment: Broooo. I found the issue. the ```from``` field in lookup should be plural. The way it is saved in MongoDB. Not singular as we do it in Mongoose model.

Comment: So I just changed ```category``` to ```categories``` and it worked.

Comment: Please post it as an answer

Comment: Just saw your updates. I went ahead and updated the live demo, as well as the code within my answer. Super glad that worked for you, my friend! Have a good day.

Comment: Thank you again and please take care